# WPF Binding Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am attempting to convert this xaml binding to it's C# counterpart for various reasons:

```
<ListView x:Name="eventListView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="0">
    <local:EventCell x:Name="cell" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource ListViewWidthConverter}, ElementName=eventListView, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</ListView>
```

I've read a lot of questions already that had similar problems and came up with this code:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = eventListView;
b.Path = new PropertyPath(cell.Width);
b.Converter = new ListViewWidthConverter();
b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
cell.SetBinding(ListView.ActualWidthProperty, b);
```

But the C# code won't compile, I am pretty lost as to why.

Comment: Why doesn't the code compile? What's the error?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the constructor of the `PropertyPath` the `cell.Width` gets the value, you either want `EventCell.ActualWidthProperty` to get the DP-field if it is a DP, or use the string, `"ActualWidth"`.

When translating XAML like this, just set the path in the Binding constructor which is the same constructor used in XAML (as the path is not qualified):

```
Binding b = new Binding("ActualWidth");
```

*(If your binding were to be translated back to XAML it would be something like `{Binding Path=123.4, ...}`, note that the `Path` property is qualified as you did not use the constructor to set it)*

**Edit:** Also the binding needs to be set on the `EventCell.WidthProperty` of course, you cannot set the `ActualWidth`, it seems your logic was inverted...

Comment: Still gives me a XamlParseException was unhandled.
with
b.Path = new PropertyPath(EventCell.WidthProperty);
or
b.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth");

Comment: @xvpower: See my edit (and `PropertyPath(EventCell.WidthProperty)` is wrong, that should be `PropertyPath(EventCell.ActualWidthProperty)`)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to make the `ActualWidthProperty` throw a `NotifyPropertyChanged` event.  Otherwise, the binding will not know to update when the property changes.  Whenever I've done bindings, I've always had to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

You might try extending the list view class and then implementing it on the width property.  I gave a similar answer here: [WPF Toolkit DataGrid column resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016436/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-column-resize-event/6944737#6944737)

Comment: ActualWidth is probably already a DependencyProperty of the control.

Comment: Ah, it turns out that it is.  In that case, you don't need to implement the property changed event

Comment: WPF bindings treat DependencyProperties differently (more efficiently) than INotifyPropertyChanged ones. So if DP there, use it